# Mobilefisrt console service notification not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Have changed the status of my app to Active notifying in mobilefirst console, and I have tried to send custom notification message to app, but the application on device is not receiving the message sent from mobilefirst console.
In the app, we are using WL.Client.connect, and we are using adapters as well, any suggestions ? 
Where can we check whether this feature is disabled in worklight?
Any mobilefirst trace that we can enable to identify the issue?
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the feature, it's either used (by setting the app *version* to Remote Notify) or not used.

- The message appears only once during the application lifecycle (unless you send a different message), so make sure you didn't miss it.
- Additionally, make sure that in case you have multiple versions of your app, that you are looking at the correct app version that you've sent the message to.